# Python Matplotlib – Bar chart on their representing sampling position on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to plot sampling data of different groups in a stacked bar chart. The sampling was performed at different km. The distance between each sampling point is not equal. Normally, when plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.bar or pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar, the bars are plotted one behind the other. Their km-value isn't represented on the x-axis. How I can plot stacked bar plots at their representing km-position on the x-axis?

Code of a standard bar plot with `pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Group 1': {-60.0:0, -20.0:0, 12.5:0, 62.0:0, 123.8:0, 181.0: 5.013532366071429e-06, 225.2: 0.00010224713604266826, 248.0: 0.0002520240051269531, 274.9: 0.0006304542296807856, 304.2: 0.0009587457616051962, 331.0: 0.0021422429744175505}, 'Group 2': {-60.0: 0.0003144776457026891, -20.0: 5.43150903588747e-05, 12.5: 0.00012757662141348495, 62.0: 6.852403753623154e-05, 123.8: 5.980538377849872e-05, 181.0: 5.000001780657088e-05, 225.2: 0.00010152032391840468, 248.0: 0.0005436288535458056, 274.9: 0.00038244130009346957, 304.2: 0.00023423789360943164, 331.0: 9.508221455006986e-05}, 'Group 3': {-60.0: 0.00021804919790451726, -20.0: 0.0002884471518114942, 12.5: 0.00024001954291413006, 62.0: 0.00020780311751064946, 123.8:0, 181.0: 0.0003548555407567293, 225.2: 0.0011448858440205976, 248.0: 0.0031436022397010425, 274.9: 0.001858462242669843, 304.2: 0.0019485330483867962, 331.0: 0.0017062062250634059}} )
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.set_ylabel('TM [mg/l]')
ax.set_xlabel('km')
plt.tight_layout()
```

For clearance:

Standard bar plot
[image]

What I want
[image]

Comment: *"Normally, when plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.bar, each bar represents a category"* that is not true. matplotlib bar plots are numeric by default. You do not share any code here which would allow to see where the problem lies. See [mcve].

Comment: You're using pandas bar plots. Those are categorical indeed. Use `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the hint of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) I used `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` instead of `pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar` to get what I wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group 1': {-60.0:0, -20.0:0, 12.5:0, 62.0:0, 123.8:0, 181.0: 5.013532366071429e-06, 225.2: 0.00010224713604266826, 248.0: 0.0002520240051269531, 274.9: 0.0006304542296807856, 304.2: 0.0009587457616051962, 331.0: 0.0021422429744175505}, 'Group 2': {-60.0: 0.0003144776457026891, -20.0: 5.43150903588747e-05, 12.5: 0.00012757662141348495, 62.0: 6.852403753623154e-05, 123.8: 5.980538377849872e-05, 181.0: 5.000001780657088e-05, 225.2: 0.00010152032391840468, 248.0: 0.0005436288535458056, 274.9: 0.00038244130009346957, 304.2: 0.00023423789360943164, 331.0: 9.508221455006986e-05}, 'Group 3': {-60.0: 0.00021804919790451726, -20.0: 0.0002884471518114942, 12.5: 0.00024001954291413006, 62.0: 0.00020780311751064946, 123.8:0, 181.0: 0.0003548555407567293, 225.2: 0.0011448858440205976, 248.0: 0.0031436022397010425, 274.9: 0.001858462242669843, 304.2: 0.0019485330483867962, 331.0: 0.0017062062250634059}})

width = 15
bottom = 0

for i in df.columns:
    plt.bar(df.index, df[i], width=width, bottom=bottom)
    bottom += df[i]

plt.ylabel('TM [mg/l]')
plt.xlabel('km')
plt.legend(df.columns)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: stacked bar plot with sampling x-position]

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyplot.plot(data = df) function from matplotlib(with default values). It will auto format xticks. 
Or else you can try pyplot.xticks and pyplot.set_xticks to customize your needs.

Comment: Pass bar as it is and use pyplot.xticks and pyplot.set_xticks. You can find useful documentation here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py

Comment: For example when I use ax.set_xticks(range(-20, 20)) to arrange the x-axis between -20 km and +20 km, I got this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/CIO6mDy). The bars stay on their positions 0-10.